# Mongodb MapReduce returning unexpected result

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

[Scripting running in Mongos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o0oc.png)

The emit should have been 378, but it only have 79 in result. It would return 100 if limit was set to 100.

See the screenshot

Comment: Please insert your query, result and data inside your post

Comment: Please see the screenshot or send you an email

Comment: Copy paste in your post instead of screenshot so people can copy paste in mongo shell to reproduce your issue